# Mongo findOne access properties issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

Ok maybe i don't see it but this query looks fine to me:

```
db.bind('links');
db.links.findOne({ short_id: req.params.id }, function(err, link) {
    console.log(link["post_id"]); // I also tried console.log(link.post_id)
    res.jsonp(link);
});
```

But the error says: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'post_id' of null". Then i tried to remove that console.log, and i got the output on the browser, so link is not null it has some value, but why it's trowing and error when accessing it's properties, any ideas?

Comment: It's "null", but jsonp returns:

    {"_id":"549d5bfbbf2fd9fd0bb61118","branch_link":"http://branchmetrics.com/","creator_id":"543e4354db824a4e603c5ffa","created_at":"2014-12-26T13:00:43.855Z","post_id":"54450c9fd771aa9b05838c86","short_id":"mk8EN5kX","__v":0}

Comment: And err is also null.

Comment: What is your document structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so it was not a mongo issue after all, it was my routes...
Because my route structure is like /, /:id?, and because of some reason the code was called twice, the first time it worked but the second time it was null.

So all i had to do is to check if id exists:

```
router.get('/:id?', function(req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  if (!id) {
    next();
    return;
  }
  ...
});
```